# YII2 - How to Display Defferent Value of Two Relation on Same Table

Tags: php, sql, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I have a football match function. But always display same team on home or away.

Here's my code,

Model [Match] :

```
use app\models\Team;

...

public function getTeam()
{
return $this->hasOne(Team::className(), ['id' => 'home', 'id' => 'away']);
}

...
```

- Team model is list of all team
- Match table only keep id of Team on Home Field and Away Field

Model [MatchSearch] :

```
....

    public $team_home;
    public $team_away;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['home', 'away'], 'integer'],
            [['team_home', 'team_away'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }

    ...

    public function search($params)
    {
        $query = Match::find()->joinWith(['team']);

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        $dataProvider->sort->attributes['team_home'] = [
            'asc' => ['team.team' => SORT_ASC],
            'desc' => ['team.team' => SORT_DESC],
        ];

        $dataProvider->sort->attributes['team_away'] = [
            'asc' => ['team.team' => SORT_ASC],
            'desc' => ['team.team' => SORT_DESC],
        ];

        $this->load($params);

        if (!$this->validate()) {
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'home' => $this->home,
            'away' => $this->away,
        ]);

        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'team.team', $this->team_home])
              ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'team.team', $this->team_away]);

        return $dataProvider;
    }
```

Views [Index] :

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        [
            'attribute' => 'home',
            'value' => function($data) {
                return $data->team->team;
            },
        ],
        [
            'attribute' => 'away',
            'value' => function($data) {
                return $data->team->team;
            },
        ],

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

But the result always show the Away team both Home or Away :

```
Home :
  Team Away
Away :
  Team Away
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use  inner join

```
 $query = Match::find()
      ->innerJoin('team_tname as home', '`team_taame`.`id` = `match_table_name`.`home`')
      ->innerJoin('team_taname as away', '`team_name`.`id` = `match_table_name`.`away`');
```

the you should refer  to the column name using the proper table alias

Comment: Another error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'team'